# tiny mce display tags in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce, html-safe

I am trying to store content of tinyMCE into "detail" coloumn.

Now when I display the content it displays wit all the `<p>` tags `<i>` tags etc.
This Is a security feature in rails3 .

But I don't want the `<p>` tags to be displayed , I want it to be rendered as HTML.

One way I found was `<%= something.detail.html_safe %>`

the other way I thought was to create a function in model like

```
def detail_safe
    return self.detail.html_safe
  end
```

and display using `<%= something.detail_safe %>`

Either ways I need to change the `<%= %>` tag at many places. Is there an easier solution? Or should I manually change at every place?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model:

```
def detail
  self[:detail].html_safe if self[:detail]
end
```

Please note that you will always get html_safe output in this case when you do `model_object.detail`.

Comment: Wouldn't this trigger an infinite loop?

Comment: Please look at the edit. The idea was to override ActiveRecord attribute accessor.

Comment: def detail
  self.detail.html_safe 
end 
 would lead to infinte loop :)

Answer (score 1):

Not matter how you do it, you will have to change all of your `<%=  %>`.

Your options are:

```
<%= something.detail_safe %>
<%= something.detail.html_safe %>
<%= raw something.detail %>
```

The only other option I can think of is turning off XSS protection - but don't do that!